# How to use Python-Virtual Environment

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I am new to Python-Virtual environment and confused in its working pattern. I created an environment using 'virtualenv project-venv'. And activated it using 'source project-venv/bin/activate'. When I ran 'pip freeze' only wheel** package was shown. Then I changed my directory to my project and ran 'python Launcher.py'. Surprisingly, the class imported all the project's required libraries from Python's global package, while logically that should not. I didn't get the reason.

Thanks

Comment: Please someone help me.. I really need the solution. :(